# Sort and copy data based on a date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that would allow me to extract data from an array to send an email.

The sorting must be done according to the comments. The goal is to detect the date of the day, for example today 22/08/2022, and to extract the line in another page by erasing in the comment box, the comments which are not dated today , ie have the whole line with the last comment in the comment box. On the other hand, if there is no comment dating from today, the line must not be selected or copied.

However, no matter what code I enter, I cannot sort the data according to the date and only retrieve today's comment, knowing that in this excel I only have a few lines but I have to be able to use it for 1000 rows.

How should I go about it?

Thank you and have good day

My example table

[image: 1]

The result that I try to have

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub TodaysComments()

    Dim srcWs       As Worksheet
    Dim destWs      As Worksheet
    Dim myCell      As Range
    Dim rngToCopy   As Range
    
    ' Set source and find comments column
    Set srcWs = Worksheets("Source")
    Set myCell = srcWs.Cells.Find("Commentaires")
    If myCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cannot find column 'Commentaires'!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set and clear destination
    Set destWs = Worksheets("Filtered")
    destWs.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Copy Header
    RngCopy CurrentRow(myCell), destWs.Range("A1")

    ' Loop over comments
    NextCell myCell
    Do While myCell.Value <> ""
        ' Search for today's date
        If Not myCell.Find(Today) Is Nothing Then
            ' Aggregate rows to copy
            Set rngToCopy = RngUnion(rngToCopy, CurrentRow(myCell))
        End If
        NextCell myCell
    Loop
    
    ' No comments today
    If rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No 'Commentaires' rows meet criteria!", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Copy rows to destination
    RngCopy rngToCopy, destWs.Range("A2")
    
    ' Clear old comments from destination
    Set myCell = destWs.Cells(2, myCell.Column)
    Do While myCell.Value <> ""
        ClearOldComments myCell
        NextCell myCell
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Done!", vbInformation
End Sub

Private Sub RngCopy(SrcRng As Range, DestRng As Range)
    SrcRng.Copy
    DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    DestRng.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Function CurrentRow(myCell As Range) As Range
    Set CurrentRow = Range(myCell, myCell.Worksheet.Cells(myCell.Row, 1))
End Function

Private Sub NextCell(myCell As Range)
    Set myCell = myCell.Offset(1, 0)
End Sub

Function RngUnion(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range) As Range
    If Rng2 Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 91 ' Object variable not set
    If Rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set RngUnion = Rng2
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set RngUnion = Union(Rng1, Rng2)
End Function

Private Sub ClearOldComments(myCell As Range)
    Dim Comments As Variant
    Dim i        As Long

    Comments = VBA.Split(myCell.Value, vbNewLine)
    For i = LBound(Comments) To UBound(Comments)
        ' NOTE: We assume there is only one comment per day.
        If InStr(Comments(i), Today) Then
            myCell.Value = Comments(i)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Should not be possible
    Err.Raise 93 ' Invalid pattern string
End Sub

Function Today() As String
    Today = FormatDateTime(Date, vbGeneralDate)
End Function
```